# Keyboard Listener when user clicks on a youtube iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, keylistener

I am having a big issue with this. I have a Javascript Website that detects the users left and right arrow to switch between Divs. But when the users clicks on a YouTube Embed say to Mute or Unmute Volume, the keyEvent stops working until the user clicks back on any part of the page.

Is there any way I can mantain the key events working even when the user has clicked on the YouTube embed in an iFrame?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more and show us a demo if possible

Comment: Yes I have a window keylistener event (document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) =>) that detects when the user users the left and right arrow on the keyboard. I also have a Youtube Embed code inside an iframe that plays a Video. If the user clicks on the youtube Embed to pause, play or mute the video. The focus stays on the iframe and the key listener stops working. I cannot have that happen since the keylistener needs to be working all the time.